# NSURLDownload and self-signed certificates

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest, nsurldownload

I'm attempting to use NSURLDownload to download files from a web server with a self-signed certificate. This normally results in:

`NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9812)`

or similar.

According to the [NSURLDownloadDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLDownloadDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSURLDownloadDelegate), the following methods are supposed to be called during authentication:

```
- (BOOL)download:(NSURLDownload *)download canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace
- (void)download:(NSURLDownload *)download didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
```

As mentioned in other SO answers, those methods can be used to allow the use of self-signed certificates. Unfortunately, they are not being called.

All other delegate methods work as expected.

Simplified code (not much to see here):

```
- (int)retrieve:(NSString *)urlString
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

    downloadComplete = false;
    downloadSucceeded = true;

    NSURLDownload *download = [[NSURLDownload alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    if (!download) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Download failed\n");
    }

    while ((downloadComplete == false) && [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]]);

    return (downloadSucceeded == true);
}

- (BOOL)download:(NSURLDownload *)download canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace
{
    NSLog(@"download:canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace");

    return [protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust];
}

- (void)download:(NSURLDownload *)download didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    NSLog(@"download:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge");

    if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust])
        if([challenge.protectionSpace.host isEqualToString:@"myhost.mydomain.com"])
            [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];

    [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```

I have worked around the issue by scrapping `NSURLDownload` in favor of `NSURLConnection`, but I'd still like to know what's going on. (The equivalent `NSURLConnectionDelegate` methods are called as expected.)

Has anyone successfully used `NSURLDownload` with self-signed certificates?

Comment: Have you tried NSURLDownload since you added the NSURLConnection delegate methods?

Comment: I never did get self-signed + NSURLDownload working. The appropriate delegates simply didn't get called. I abandoned the NSURLDownload approach in favor of the more modern NSURLSession.